# JavaScript library to get dimensions of non-transparent content inside PNG image

Tags: javascript, image-processing

Is there a way to find out dimensions of the image without the surrounding transparent margin?
I am primarily interested in rectangles which are surrounded by bigger transparent rectangle.

If for example the drawing is a circle with radius 10px, which is in an PNG image (100px x 100px) with transparent background, then the resulting
"real" image dimensions would be a bounding rectangle of 20px by 20px.

I am aware that if there were several objects in the image, that would result in a bounding rectangle around all these objects.

So I guess the question is how to find out the tightest bounding box around a drawing within an image with transparent background.

I am looking for a JS library or method which can find this out.